# How to make link of String in Sms verification in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to verify account through sms code,sms code sent by best sms library in node.js. i want to make code copyable or selectable but can't do this just getting code in simple string.please help me.Thanks in advance

```
"use strict";

var request = require('request');
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const config = require('config')

const sendMessageToNumber = (toNumber, code) => {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request({
        method: 'GET',
        uri: config.bestsms.endpoint,
        qs: {
            user: encodeURI(process.env.BESTSMS_USERNAME),
            pass: encodeURI(process.env.BESTSMS_PASSWORD),
            from: encodeURI(config.bestsms.from),
            to: encodeURI(toNumber),
            text: encodeURI(config.bestsms.message + code.bold())
        }
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log("Status of sending SMS: "+ body)
        if (body) {
            resolve(body);
        }
        reject(error)
    });
});
}
 module.exports = {
sendMessageToNumber
}
```

Comment: Your script sends the code to the user's device using best SMS' servers.
Whether the code is copyable & selectable depends on the SMS app installed on user's device. You cannot force that app to make your code copyable or selectable.
Exception: you have a front-end app installed on user's phone which intercepts SMS and reads the code.

Comment: @AdiB So how can i do this for my sms code ? can you suggest anything ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know - you can't, not with SMS.

SMS are simple text only.

Android and iOS can decide how to format parts of the message like URLs and numbers. So you can test several options with different devices to find your perfect formatting.

You can maybe try with MMS, like [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108345/how-did-starbucks-send-bold-text-in-an-mms-to-messages/108351#108351) answer

Comment: So how the other app do this ? like whats app or fb or google verification code we get the code string is copyable  or selectable ? how they do this

Answer (score 1):

It's not them, it's your messages app. Try to send the same message to yourself and the result will be the same.